# run into Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in lodash's reduce function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am beginner using reduce function and lodash library, I am trying to have array referred to as result here, but I run into some situation like below.

```
          let result: Array<number> = [];
            result.push(1); // [1]

            _.reduce(array, function(result, el, idx) {
                if(el.node === array[child_index].parent) {
                    result.push(parseInt(idx)); // [2]
                    return result; 
                }
            }, result);
```

Could I ask why I was able to push the value at [1] while I was not able to push the value at [2], Actually, I run into this error message in [2].
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined, 
         I am using lodash for reduce function. I also tried concat it returned same error. If anyone had same issues, could I get some advice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `result` as a default action to prevent the error if the `if` statement is not true:

```
_.reduce(array, function(result, el, idx) {
  if (el.node === array[child_index].parent) {
    result.push(parseInt(idx));
  }
  return result;
}, result);
```

Comment: No worries @AnnaLee, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted.